# How to undo when using QScintilla setText?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, pyqt5, scintilla, qscintilla

Let me start by posting some little helper functions I'll use to formulate my questions:

```
import textwrap
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PyQt5.Qsci import QsciScintilla
from PyQt5.Qt import *  # noqa


def set_style(sci):
    # Set default font
    sci.font = QFont()
    sci.font.setFamily('Consolas')
    sci.font.setFixedPitch(True)
    sci.font.setPointSize(8)
    sci.font.setBold(True)
    sci.setFont(sci.font)
    sci.setMarginsFont(sci.font)
    sci.setUtf8(True)

    # Set paper
    sci.setPaper(QColor(39, 40, 34))

    # Set margin defaults
    fontmetrics = QFontMetrics(sci.font)
    sci.setMarginsFont(sci.font)
    sci.setMarginWidth(0, fontmetrics.width("000") + 6)
    sci.setMarginLineNumbers(0, True)
    sci.setMarginsForegroundColor(QColor(128, 128, 128))
    sci.setMarginsBackgroundColor(QColor(39, 40, 34))
    sci.setMarginType(1, sci.SymbolMargin)
    sci.setMarginWidth(1, 12)

    # Set indentation defaults
    sci.setIndentationsUseTabs(False)
    sci.setIndentationWidth(4)
    sci.setBackspaceUnindents(True)
    sci.setIndentationGuides(True)
    sci.setFoldMarginColors(QColor(39, 40, 34), QColor(39, 40, 34))

    # Set caret defaults
    sci.setCaretForegroundColor(QColor(247, 247, 241))
    sci.setCaretWidth(2)

    # Set edge defaults
    sci.setEdgeColumn(80)
    sci.setEdgeColor(QColor(221, 221, 221))
    sci.setEdgeMode(sci.EdgeLine)

    # Set folding defaults (http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#Folding)
    sci.setFolding(QsciScintilla.CircledFoldStyle)

    # Set wrapping
    sci.setWrapMode(sci.WrapNone)

    # Set selection color defaults
    sci.setSelectionBackgroundColor(QColor(61, 61, 52))
    sci.resetSelectionForegroundColor()

    # Set scrollwidth defaults
    sci.SendScintilla(QsciScintilla.SCI_SETSCROLLWIDTHTRACKING, 1)

    # Current line visible with special background color
    sci.setCaretLineBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 224))

    # Set multiselection defaults
    sci.SendScintilla(QsciScintilla.SCI_SETMULTIPLESELECTION, True)
    sci.SendScintilla(QsciScintilla.SCI_SETMULTIPASTE, 1)
    sci.SendScintilla(QsciScintilla.SCI_SETADDITIONALSELECTIONTYPING, True)


def set_state1(sci):
    sci.clear_selections()
    base = "line{} state1"
    view.setText("\n".join([base.format(i) for i in range(10)]))
    for i in range(0, 10, 2):
        region = (len(base) * i, len(base) * (i + 1) - 1)
        if i == 0:
            view.set_selection(region)
        else:
            view.add_selection(region)


def set_state2(sci):
    base = "line{} state2"
    view.setText("\n".join([base.format(i) for i in range(10)]))
    for i in range(1, 10, 2):
        region = (len(base) * i, len(base) * (i + 1) - 1)
        if i == 1:
            view.set_selection(region)
        else:
            view.add_selection(region)


class Editor(QsciScintilla):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        set_style(self)

    def clear_selections(self):
        sci = self
        sci.SendScintilla(sci.SCI_CLEARSELECTIONS)

    def set_selection(self, r):
        sci = self
        sci.SendScintilla(sci.SCI_SETSELECTION, r[1], r[0])

    def add_selection(self, r):
        sci = self
        sci.SendScintilla(sci.SCI_ADDSELECTION, r[1], r[0])

    def sel(self):
        sci = self
        regions = []

        for i in range(sci.SendScintilla(sci.SCI_GETSELECTIONS)):
            regions.append(
                sci.SendScintilla(sci.SCI_GETSELECTIONNSTART, i),
                sci.SendScintilla(sci.SCI_GETSELECTIONNEND, i)
            )

        return sorted(regions)
```

I've got a couple of questions actually:

**Question 1)**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = Editor()
    set_state1(view)
    view.move(1000, 100)
    view.resize(800, 300)
    view.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I'll get this (you can see the question in the below snapshot):

[image]

**Question 2)**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = Editor()
    set_state1(view)
    set_state2(view)
    view.move(1000, 100)
    view.resize(800, 300)
    view.show()
    app.exec_()
```

How can I modify the code so I'll be able to restore state1 when pressing ctrl+z?

Right now when using ctrl+z you won't be able to get state1:

[image]

mainly because how [setText](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciScintilla.html#a5786917722e156e26d6afca807d05fee) behaves:

> Replaces all of the current text with text. Note that the undo/redo
>   history is cleared by this function.

I've already tried some of the functions posted in the [undo and redo](https://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#UndoAndRedo) docs but no luck so far.

For instance, one of my attempts has been first selecting all text and then using [replaceSelectedText](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciScintilla.html#a48f53865418cf2ebd5126d2ee5e9d1dd) and finally restoring the selections from the previous state manually, the result was ugly (i don't want the editor scrolling messing up when undoing/redoing)... Basically, I'd like to get the same feeling than SublimeText.

Btw, this is a little minimal example but in the real-case I'll be accumulating a bunch of operations without committing to scintilla very often... that's why I'm interested to figure out how to rollback to a previous state when using the undoable setText... Said otherwise, i'd like to avoid using Scintilla functions such as [insertAt](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciScintilla.html#afba4d5b30fae60dab7b4279c580beb8c), replaceSelectedText or similars... as I'm using python string builtin functions to modify the buffer internally.

EDIT:

I'm pretty sure beginUndoAction & endUndoAction won't help me to answer question2 but... what about `SCI_ADDUNDOACTION`? Although the [docs](https://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_ADDUNDOACTION) are pretty confusing though... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**:
The last selection added is automatically set as the `Main` selection. To remove it, add line `sci.SendScintilla(sci.SCI_SETMAINSELECTION, -1)` at the end of the `set_state1` function.

**Question 2**:

- The way you described it by storing the selections, using the `replaceSelectedText`, and then using `setCursorPosition` / `reselecting all selections` and `setFirstVisibleLine` to restore the scroll position is one way to go.
- Looking at the C++ source of the `setText` function:

```cpp
// Set the given text.
void QsciScintilla::setText(const QString &text)
{
    bool ro = ensureRW();

    SendScintilla(SCI_SETTEXT, ScintillaBytesConstData(textAsBytes(text)));
    SendScintilla(SCI_EMPTYUNDOBUFFER);

    setReadOnly(ro);
}
```

You could try setting the text using `sci.SendScintilla(sci.SCI_SETTEXT, b"some text")`, which doesn't reset the undo/redo buffer.